# Can't receive an HTTP response from Mule

Tags: java, http, mule

I am creating a basic service component that takes a URL as input  at *http inbound endpoint*. Code snippet from the mule-config file is as follows:

```
    <service name="follow">
        <inbound>
            <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8765/follow/" synchronous="true"/>
        </inbound>
        <component class="org.mule.application.mytwitter.Follow" />
    </service>
```

and the function that is called from the Java component class is:

```
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        MuleMessage msg = eventContext.getMessage();
        String str = msg.getStringProperty("http.request", null);

        msg.setPayload(str);
        msg.setStringProperty("http.status","200");
        msg.setStringProperty("Content-Type","text/html");
        System.out.println("Reached here:" + str);
        return msg;
    }
```

I wish to receive an HTTP response(payload) by hitting the service through CURL as:

> curl -vv "http://localhost:8765/follow/"

but I'm not receiving any payload:

```
> * About to connect() to localhost port 8765 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... connected
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8765 (#0)
> GET /follow/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15
> Host: localhost:8765
> Accept: */*
> 
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Date: Tue, 27 Dec 2011 03:14:00 IST
< Server: Mule Core/2.1.2
< Expires: Tue, 27 Dec 2011 03:14:00 IST
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection #0
```

Am I missing something? The function in component class is being called and output is printed in console.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you get in the console? What's after "Reached here:"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind guys. i figured out something and it works fine now. there's an attribute called *syncResponse* for *inbound-endpoint*. Setting it to *true* makes it work synchronously. I think some problem to do with Mule 2.1.2 or maybe some system settings.

Answer (score 1):

Are you intentionally using such an old version of mule? There's a much newer 3.2.1 version available. And I suggest you to move to flow-style messaging instead of services.

But to answer your problem, if you want to have the response payload to print out, then you should add a string transformer to you configuration. I don't remember exactly how to configure this to the service element, but if you use flow's then you can add a response block to the end of the flow.

`<http:http-response-to-string-transformer />`

I hope this helps.